# soap-error: Parsing Wsql: couldn't load from "xyz.wsdl" faild to load external

Tags: magento2, soap, soap-api-v2

In magento2 i created a module in which i used `soap api` for request, response, everything working fine in my local but when i running on server.
I am getting below error

'Fatal Error: 'SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from "xyz.wsdl" faild to load external.

i read some answer in stackoverflow and applied solution. i added

IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX www.example.com in our etc/hosts file on server.

but problem is remain same.

Comment: have you got any solution for issue ? i am facing same problem

Comment: yes my url was wrong, there was some space thats why this error was coming

Comment: @Yogesh Karodiya: have you got any solution for issue ?

Comment: @PurushotamSharma read my comment